# Scoping a relation using 'through' with conditions on the 'through' relation

Tags: php, yii

I'm having trouble scoping a complex relation:

- I have an `object` active record and each has a relation to some `subject`s through an `objectSubject` relation.
- The type of the `subject` (in relation to the `object`) is defined in the `objectSubject`.
- Each `object` has zero or one `subject` relation of each type

I'd like to be able to query a specific subject by using something akin to:

```
$object->subject(array('scopes'=>array('typed'=>$type)));
```

but have only managed:

```
$object->objectSubject(array('scopes'=>array('typed'=>$type)))->subject;
```

which breaks if there is no subject of that type. I'm aware that I can get round this, but I'd like this behavior for more complicated criteria.

I have the relations set up in the `Object` model as:

```
'objectSubject'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'ObjectSubject', 'object_id'),
'subject'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'Subject', array('subject_id'=>'id'),
  'through'=>'objectSubject'),
```

I am using `HAS_ONE` so that I don't get an array.